# how to run two update queries in one?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run 2 update queries as one `$result, Is this possible, and if so can someone please show me where am I going wrong with the below query?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptb_users (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, password )
    VALUES('NULL','NULL','" . $firstname . "','" . $lastname . "','" . $email . "',MD5('" . $password . "'))";

mysql_query($query) or dieerr();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET ptb_users.user_id=ptb_users.id UPDATE ptb_users SET ptb_users.account_type= \"Client\"");
```

Comment: as an aside, PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: `'NULL'` will save the *literal string* `'NULL'` into your database.  If you want `NULL`, lose the quotes.

Comment: Note that without `WHERE` clause your `UPDATE`s will alter all records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no `WHERE` clause on your `UPDATE`s, you can combine them like this:

```
UPDATE ptb_users SET ptb_users.user_id = ptb_users.id,
  ptb_users.account_type = 'Client'
```

**EDIT**: If you want to `UPDATE` the row, you just `INSERT`ed, then just add `WHERE ptb_users.id = $id` (you can use `mysql_insert_id()` to get the ID).

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptb_users (id, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, password )
    VALUES('NULL','NULL','" . $firstname . "','" . $lastname . "','" . $email . "',MD5('" . $password . "'))";

mysql_query($query) or dieerr();
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET ptb_users.user_id = ptb_users.id,
      ptb_users.account_type = 'Client' WHERE ptb_users.id =".$id);
```

Comment: would it be possible to insert a where clause or have something that conditions this update to say only update account_type to 'client' for the current query being executed? otherwise this changes all account_types in the table and i dont want this

Comment: @JamesTanner: What do you mean by "current query being executed"?  Which row(s) do you want to be updated with which value(s)?  If you want one row to have both values updated, then just add ``WHERE `column`= 'value'`` *after* the `SET` clause.

Comment: there are two registration forms on my site one for members and one for clients. this query runs as part of a registration form for clients, the values get inserted and the result updates a column so that id = user_id that bits fine, the bit i want to concentrate on is i also need the result to say for this particular registration/insert where 'Member' is the default value for account_type in the table i need it to get updated to 'client' for this registration

Answer (score 0):

Mysql* functions are deprecated. Use [PDO/mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

As a security measure, mysql* functions wont allow you to execute multiple queries. You can with Mysql* however, you should prepare your statement before executing.

Comment: Won't do. `mysql_query()` can't run multiple queries

Comment: Good call. I should reverse those statements. Use mysqli THEN put a semi-colon...

Comment: @DevinYoung: I *highly* doubt MySQLi will let you run multiple queries in one command.

Comment: Still, using `mysqli_multi_query` is not that trivial. You need to retrieve results from all queries before you can issue any new queries. In most cases you will just want to call `mysqli_query()` multiple times.

Comment: You can: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php . Although that doesn't mean it's a good idea :P